# join within a same collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Pardon my ignorance if it is a very basic question.
ABC collection in MongoDB has the following schema.

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "store": 5051,
        "catg": "XYZ",
     },
    "category": {
        "name": "XYZ",
        "id": "CL141778",
        }
}

I need to query (where "metadata.catg" == "category.name")
```

What is the best way to do it without using mongoose dbref ?

Comment: i just mentioned join to explain what i want. so does this mean that i have to take care of this in the application ?

Comment: Yes. While there are some ways of using the aggregation framework to do cross field comparison, I wouldn't recommend them if you had something that was more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you can not compare two fields values with each other in a query. What I expect is that you need to redesign your schema. You need to look at how you *query* (and update) as supposed to thinking MongoDB is yet another RDBMs.

Show us the real schema, some example documents and a few query types that you need to run and I can see if I can help.